# How to know when a driver with an ipad starts/stops driving using ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I want to know when an ipad user starts/stops driving or moving in a vehicle. I am able to get the current location using CLLocationManager. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can detect changes in velocity using the accelerometer (CoreMotion framework, I believe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use

```
if (location.getSpeed() > speedThreshold) {
  status = DRIVING;
}
```

Comment: make sure that you have set acuracy 'Best'